# ASP.NET MVC5 - Nullable model property always losing its value (null) when editing model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

When I Edit my model, all properties are saved correctly except for a nullable property which always loses its value in the process.

I have tried to hide the property in my view as such:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)
```

In my controller's Edit method I tried to:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(ItemViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var item= db.Items.Find(viewModel.ItemId);
                Mapper.Map<ItemViewModel, Item>(viewModel, item);
                //db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                if (TryUpdateModel(item))
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserId", "Username", viewModel.UserId);
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

I also tried without the TryUpdateModel and with the UpdateModel(model) method. I even tried reassign it the property value from the ViewModel to the Model manually just before saving the changes.

When I put breakpoints throughout the method I can see that the property still holds its value but as soon as I hit Save it becomes null.

Note that if I uncomment the EntityState.Modified line I am no longer losing the property value but I am handling this stuff in my DbContext (I have different type of edit events for different property and having this line of code uncommented in my controller seems to triger all of my edit events even if nothing changed).

Please note that this property is also a Foreign key (not sure if it actually matters here)

Comment: I don't see where your passing the object to be saved to the database. From what I can see your calling SaveChanges() on an object that the database doesn't know about.

Comment: TryUpdateModel is being passed the model (my original post had to wrong model name, I fixed it now). All the edited properties are saved properly so this works fine. It works even without the TryUpdatModel and simply calling the db.SaveChanges() method. My nullable property still looses its value though.

Comment: Why did you comment out `db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified`?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I'm having different models that handles different type of edits (for logging purposes) and having this line of code triggers all the editevents even if only let's say, the Location property is updated. This indeed seem to cause me to lose my nullable property though. I'm trying to understand all this is related and failing to do so so far.

Comment: I see that you have mapped the model to an item but you have not reassigned the value. Add the reassingment to the mapper call and I believe it will fix your problem

Comment: @Orphu.of.io: the reason it's doing that is because of the mapping. Entity Framework has property-level change tracking, but because you're blanketedly mapping everything, everything is changed, even if it's the same value (i.e. Entity Framework knows that `set` was called).

Comment: @Robert Thanks Robert, I think what you're suggesting is essentially what Chris proposed and that solved my problem. Should I reassigned every property manually in such a way? I'm looking to understand why only that one property was problematic (nullable? FK?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TryUpdateModel` doesn't actually do anything to the item passed into it. It merely runs model validation on it. Whatever values were there, remain there.

I *think* I know what the issue is, and it's related to AutoMapper. Your posted model most likely doesn't include the actual related user object, just the id you posted for that. When you map your model onto your entity, AutoMapper is replacing the value for the related user object with `null`, since the model doesn't have it. Try adding the following to your `CreateMap`:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.User, opts => opts.Ignore());
```

Comment: I modified my automapper config file as such:
 private class ItemMapping : Profile
        {
            protected override void Configure()
            {
                Mapper.CreateMap<Models.Item, ViewModels.ItemViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, opts => opts.Ignore());
                Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModels.ItemViewModel, Models.Item>().ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, opts => opts.Ignore());

            }
        }

But still not working. Is my method correct?

Comment: Oh I got it to work with .ForMember(dest => dest.User, opts => opts.Ignore()); (just like you said) instead of .ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, opts => opts.Ignore());(like I was trying to do) Thanks! I guess there's still a lot to learn :) Is it because User is an entity and UserId is just a property?

Comment: Well, more that you *want* the id mapped, because you're presumably posting that. The entity itself, you aren't posting, so you don't want AutoMapper to map that null value it's going to have on the model, since nothing was posted.

Comment: Alright! So adding that ignores the User entity but allows the UserId property to be mapped, got it. Is is because UserId is a foreign key pointing to the User entity?

Comment: Again, it's simply about what's posted and what's not. Or more generally, what exists as a non-null value on the model being mapped over to your entity. When you mapped over the null value for `User`, EF looks at it like, "Oh, guess you want to remove this association then." and will actually end up nulling out the foreign key as well when it saves the entity back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

What I am saying is all of your code is correct except for this line:

```
 Mapper.Map<ItemViewModel, Item>(viewModel, item);
```

That line should be

```
 item = Mapper.Map<ItemViewModel, Item>(viewModel, item);
```

Then at some point you need to pass that to the repository:

```
 db.Update(item);
 db.SaveChanges();
```